# How to use Bokeh server to plot realtime in web

Tags: python, bokeh

- Note from maintainers: This question concerns the obsolete `bokeh-server` command that no longer exists. For up to date information about modern Bokeh server applications, see:*

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

---

---

I would like to know more about the bokeh server. I am trying to visualize some real time data coming in from twitter. How can this be done using Bokeh server?

So far I have these links for help

http://continuum.io/blog/painless_streaming_plots_w_bokeh

I am not able to plot even static plots using Bokeh server.
How can I use this code snippet here as a base point?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import bokeh.server
import bokeh.server.start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        bokeh.server.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        bokeh.server.start.stop()
        print("Shutting down bokeh-server ...")
```

Can some one throw more light on this?

Comment: I am able to run it now...Thanks buddy...Is there any example for a  time series plot?