# Bokeh scrolling plots

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm would like to make a live-updating plot using Bokeh. I've run [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/quickstart.html#using-bokeh-plot-server), but the plot resizes to show all of my data. How do I configure the plot to scroll as the data is loaded so it only shows the most recent additions? [This blog post](http://continuum.io/blog/painless_streaming_plots_w_bokeh) has a link in the comments that claims it's possible (added in version 0.4), but the link is broken. I've checked the documentation for the figure object, but should my investigation focus more on the renderer?

Related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220657/how-to-use-bokeh-server-to-plot-realtime-in-web).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (as of Bokeh 0.7.0) to have "scrolling" plots, you will need to maintain the data buffer size yourself. That is, if you only want to have at most 100 points, then as you add additionally data points, you will have to start dropping points off the beginning of your data before you pass it to the server.

We are working on integrating functionality like this into the Bokeh servers so that you can push new data to the server with a specified policy (always append, fixed buffer size, etc) and just have it work.